# How to get rid of extra irrelevant PowerShell messages

Tags: powershell

When I run `echo $PWD` I get this verbose message,

```
Path
----
/home/foo
```

How can I get rid of the irrelevant messages in the output? I simply need `/home/foo` just like in a bash environment.

Comment: `$PWD.ToString()` or just `"$PWD"` (note the quotes) works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $PWD.path
```

$PWD is an object with a member Path.